# Why the path of qmake is different?

Tags: qt

Hey guys I wanna change the path of qt but when I try to find out the path of qt, there are different path, and I don't know why.

```
ld@ld:/$ which qmake
/usr/bin/qmake

ld@ld:/$ qmake -v
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.9.5 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Comment: :/$ cd user/bin/qmake
bash: cd: user/bin/qmake: No such file or directory
btw when I wanna find the qmake dir, it could not be found out.

Comment: The `/usr/bin/qmake` is likely a link.

Comment: ***Using Qt version 5.9.5 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu*** appears to be the folder containing your Qt libraries and is not likely the location of qmake.

Comment: I typed `ls -al $(which qmake)` and got `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Dec 28  2020 /usr/bin/qmake -> qtchooser`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of details to qmake that are specific to how it's been installed and how it's being invoked. For that output -- `/usr/bin/qmake` is typically a link to `qtchooser`, which as the name implies will try to choose the most appropriate Qt version for the kit you've configured. From what you posted it looks like you're invoking the binary qmake from the command line, which is first being found in `/usr/bin`.

For the question at hand, if you want to move "Qt" I'd recommend uninstalling Qt using the maintenance tool, and then reinstalling Qt and specifying the location where you want it installed.

Answer (score 0):

you can change it by the `export` command.

like this :

```
export PATH=/home/parisa/Qt5.14.0/5.14.0/gcc_64/bin/:$PATH
```

that was the default path that was set for you and you can change it by `export` and after that, if you check it you see will be changed.

**don't forget to add your path that installed your QT.**

**output picture:**

[image]